# calculating power consumption of EV

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm trying to graph the power consumption of an EV. I have in prometheus the KWh of the battery, as well as the mileage of the car.

I imagine there must be a way to get the time of the last rise of the KWh data - that would... Afterwards I guess I could get the mileage at that point and could continue calculating from there.

Ideally I can completely do it in prometheus, as I could then have the past data as well. But maybe it makes more sense to do the actual calculating in another script and exporting that to prometheus again - but I would still need the time of the last charging cycle... Is that possible somehow?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following PromQL query:

```
((-delta(metric_kwh[$__interval])) > 0) / (delta(metric_miles[$__interval]) > 0)
```

It would return `KWh/mile` averaged over the `$__interval`. It should skip time ranges when the car wasn't moving and/or was charging.

The query uses [delta()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) function instead of `rate()` or `increase()` function, because `metric_kwh` goes down when the car moves, while [rate()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) and [increase()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) functions expect that the metric goes up.